# Correct way to find current time in milliseconds within Android draw loop

Tags: java, android, time

I'm trying to get rid of as much object creation as possible in my Android app's Draw() loop to minimize garbage collection, and I'm having trouble dealing with time.  I know of two ways to get the current time:

1) java.util.Calendar

```
long now = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
```

This works fine, but (as far as I can tell) the only way to get a Calendar object to be set to the current time is to call Calendar.getInstance(), and every call to getInstance() creates a new int[].

2) android.text.format.Time

```
Time time = new Time();
time.setToNow();
long now = time.toMillis(true);
```

This can be done without instantiating any new object each time it's called, but setToNow() appears to only be accurate to the nearest second.

How can I get the current system time, to the nearest milli, without incurring garbage collection in my Draw loop?

Comment: I used DDMS to see what is being instantiated.  It is pretty obvious because it's the only instantiation that happens in my draw loop, so it happens ~100 times per second when I add a single "calendar = Calendar.getInstance();" to Draw().

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis()`?

Comment: Nambari, you're right, but GC takes time, which can cause a visible stutter in the app's animation on slow devices, so I was trying to minimize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're just looking for [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29). Personally I would extract this static dependency to a `Clock` interface though:

```
public interface Clock {
    long currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Then you can have a `SystemClock` implementation - and a fake implementation for test purposes. If you're not unit-testing this code, it's less important.

Also note that if you're trying to measure *elapsed* time, you should look at using [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) instead.

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was forgetting something obvious!